# It is possible to publish a NPM package with FormData inside?

Tags: vue.js, npm, form-data

I have a problem with FormData, when I add a file with append I have this error in my console. This error appears only when I publish my package on npm, when I run it locally I don't have it...

My picture is inside and is File type, but on formData.append I have this error...

I also check if I have the same problem without using foreach, but It's the same problem.

smart-events is a NPM Package develop with rollup / vuejs3, this is the code which is a concern

[image: MyCode]

[image: The error]

Does someone has a solution?

Comment: Please, don't post code as images. The question lacks information. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It's unknown how the package is used and what the values in use are. At this point it can be only recommended to search for this error and see if this fits your case

Comment: Looks like the `smart-events` file is the problem. Can you get rid of it?

Comment: smart-events is the npm package with the code above, I got the error only when i link it with a real project.... I got the picture but error appears on formData.append